# Open a link in Safari with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, shortcut

In Safari, is it possible to navigate through links on the webpage by means of the keyboard?

For example, I made a search in Google and would like to open the first or second link from the web search. How could I do without using the mouse and clicking on the link?

Answer (score 3):

You can go through all links and controls in Safari using <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd>. However, that's not ideal for Google. On Google, you can press <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> and an arrow will appear next to the first result. You can then press the arrow keys to go up and down through the list.

When you have selected the link you want (either through <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> or Google’s way) you can press <kbd>↩︎ Return</kbd> to open the link in the current tab or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>↩︎ Return</kbd> to open it in a new tab.

Comment: That works if you search using the Google website. But if you use the Safari address bar for searching, pressing Tab (or Option + Tab) takes you first to the Favorites Bar bookmarks and other links above the search results, and only after that to the search results. Is there any way to go directly to the search results?

Answer (score 2):

## ⌥⇥ + ↩︎

⌥⇥ will iterate through all selectable items on a page and ↩︎ clicks the highlighted element.

[image]

To use ⇥ instead, go to Safari → Preferences → Advanced and select 'Press Tab to highlight each option on a webpage'.